# Redux-Toolkit Store does not have a valid reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux-Toolkit for the first time, followed the Quick-start in their documentation and am met with this error

> Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

I logged the reducers and the store objects to console and found that the store object from configure store doesn't have a reducer property at all.

If any of you can help out, I'd really appreciate it.

P.S : I already looked at all the other stackoverflow question on this. Nothing is relevant.

Here's my code

- store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// Redux Reducers
import { authSlice } from "./slices/authSlice";
import { projectSlice } from "./slices/projectSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authSlice.reducer,
        project: projectSlice.reducer,
    },
});
```

- authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: {
        isUserLoggedIn: false,
        userDetails: {},
    },
    reducers: {
        login: (state) => {
            state.auth.isUserLoggedIn = true;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.auth.isUserLoggedIn = false;
        },
        register: (state) => {
            state.auth.isUserLoggedIn = true;
        },
    },
});

export const { login, logout, register } = authSlice.actions;
```

Comment: I saw everything ok. Check `projectSlice`  and path to file when import

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm getting this, and there's no answer anywhere. alextrastero's answer doesn't help me.

Comment: @RaduC please paste a link to a reproducible example

Comment: @alextrastero It's facepalm time... Sorry... It turns out I was doing something wrong: somehow I had _two_ stores. I was editing the one that wasn't used and leaving empty the one that was used. I thought I had moved the store file, but my editor made a copy, I didn't realise it, and kept editing the old file, without realising what had happened. Jeez...